# If else statement to set variables for sftp host path

Tags: bash, shell

Need help with bash script - idea is to get the hostname and depending on the hostname to set a new path varaible which then will be used in a new Source variable.

Something similar to this :

```
OUTPUT="$(hostname)"

if $OUTPUT="dev"
then
set pathtosomwere=dev
elif $OUTPUT="test"
then set pathtosomewhere=test
else
set pathtosomewhere=project
fi

source=/example/$pathtosomewhere
```

Comment: This might help: [5 Bash Case Statement Examples](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-case-statement/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[` to compare values. To assign a value to a variable, don't use `set`, bash and sh are unlike (t)csh in this respect.

```sh
if [ "$OUTPUT" = dev ] ; then
    pathtosomwere=dev
elif [ "$OUTPUT" = test ] ; then
    pathtosomewhere=test
else
    pathtosomewhere=project
fi
```

It also seems the first two branches just reuse $OUTPUT as the value:

```sh
if [ "$OUTPUT" = dev -o "$OUTPUT" = test ] ; then
    pathtosomewhere=$OUTPUT
else
    pathtosomewhere=project
fi
```

which can be paraphrased using case:

```sh
case "$OUTPUT" in 
    dev|test) pathtosomewhere=$OUTPUT;;
    *) pathtosomewhere=project;;
esac
```